# Neeed to copy data from one environment to another( stage to prod fastest way)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to copy data from tables from stage to production for the tables can anyone help me in the fastest way to copy

Answer (score 0):

Use Snowflake Cloning feature. This is the fastest way to copy data between 2 databases provided that both of the databases are in the same snowflake account.